# CSS not working for one section in my HTML code

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, my CSS code doesn't work for the `.transform` class, but it does for the rest of the code.

**HTML code**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel = 'stylesheet' type="text/css" href="{% static 'change/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel = 'stylesheet' type="text/css" href='{% static 'change/css/base.css' %}'>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar-fixed-top navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" id = 'navbar'>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<section id = 'cover'>
    <div id = 'cover-caption'>
        <div class = 'container-fluid'>
            <div class = 'col-md-12' id = 'text'>
                <h1>Get Fit Fast</h1>
                <p>Get a six pack, big arms, wide shoulders in less than 12 weeks.</p>
                <p>Live your life to the fullest!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

{#Jumbotron beginning#}

<section class = 'transform'>
    <div class = 'jumbotron text-center'>
        <h1>Transformations</h1>
        <p class = 'lead'>Following our fitness program will help you lose weight and gain muscle in a short amount of time.</p>
        <p class = 'lead'>But dont take for it!</p>
        <hr class = 'focus'>
            <div class = 'container-fluid'>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3 row-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail change">
                      <img src="{% static 'change/img/ba1.png' %}">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="col-sm-3 row-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail change">
                      <img src="{% static 'change/img/ba2.png' %}">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="col-sm-3 row-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail change">
                      <img src="{% static 'change/img/ba3.png' %}">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="col-sm-3 row-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail change">
                      <img src="{% static 'change/img/ba4.png' %}">
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        <hr class = 'focus'>
        <p>Be quiet, Im doing a toast</p>
        <p class = 'lead'><a href="#" class = 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' role="button">learn more..</a></p>
 </div>
</section>


{#End of jumbotron#}

<section class ='packs'>
    <div class = 'container-fluid'>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 row-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="{% static 'change/img/arms.jpg' %}" alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>sss</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-4 row-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="{% static 'change/img/chest.jpg' %}" alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>sss</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-4 row-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="{% static 'change/img/shoulders.jpg' %}" alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>sss</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS code**

```
#navbar {
    background: #000000;
}

html, body {

    height: 100%;

}

body{
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#cover {
    background: #222222 url('../img/cover.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    color:white;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.jumbotron{
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:70px;
    background: floralwhite;
    margin-top: 23px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.container-fluid{
    padding:0 ;
}

.col-sm-3{
    background:rgba(157,52,99,0.7);
}

.transform {
    width: 100%;
}

.transform img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.packs {
    width: 100%;
}

.packs img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Why is `transform` defined twice in your CSS? Remove the first one

Comment: use ```section > .transform``` as your selector in css

Answer (score -1):

transform is a property name. Change class name to transform1 , that might work.

Comment: You better not choose transform as a class name, but it is possible